# How to find the equation of $X$?

Tags: geometry

A particle Q is moving at a constant speed $V$ in a circular path of radius $R$. P is a fixed point below $O$(the center) at a distance $r$.

X$=$PQ

How can I find an equation for $X$?
It is actually a part of a dynamics(motion of a particle in 2D) problem & I can't think of a way to find a mathematical relationship between $R$ and $r$.

I forgot to tell about $\theta$, the angle $PQ$ makes with the horizontal line.

Comment: So you mean that $x$ is the distance of the line segment $PQ$? Also, where is $Q$ when $t=0$?

Comment: Is $\theta$ the angle made by $PQ$ or $OP$?

Comment: PQ, $\theta$ varies with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a coordinate system with $O$, the center of the circle, as the origin. The radius of the circle is $R$, and the speed of the particle $Q$ is the constant $v$. Assuming the particle is at $(R, 0)$ at time $t = 0$, and then moves along the circle in the counter-clockwise direction:

$\vec{Q} = R \cos\left( \dfrac{v}{R} t \right) \hat{i} + R \sin \left( \dfrac{v}{R} t \right) \hat{j}$

Now, $P$ is directly below $O$ at a distance $r$ from it, so $P = -r\hat{j}$. Thus

$\begin{align}
\vec{PQ} & = \vec{Q} - \vec{P}\\
& = R \cos\left( \dfrac{v}{R} t \right) \hat{i} + \left[ R \sin \left( \dfrac{v}{R} t \right) + r \right] \hat{j}
\end{align}$

The distance $PQ$ is $|\vec{PQ}|$, so

$\begin{align}
PQ & = \sqrt{R^2 \cos^2 \left( \dfrac{v}{R} t \right) + \left[ R \sin \left( \dfrac{v}{R} t \right) + r \right]^2 }\\
& = \sqrt{ R^2 \cos^2 \left( \dfrac{v}{R} t \right) + R^2 \sin^2 \left( \dfrac{v}{R} t \right) + 2rR \sin \left( \dfrac{v}{R} t \right) + r^2}
\end{align}$

$\boxed{PQ = \sqrt{R^2 + r^2 + 2rR \sin \left( \dfrac{v}{R} t \right)}}$

Comment: I forgot to tell about $\theta$ as in the editted question, so $vt$ can be replaced with $\theta$ right?

Comment: No wait, how did you get Vt/R? I don't understand.

Comment: If the (constant) speed is $v$, and $R$ is the radius of the circle, then the angular speed is $v/R$.

Comment: To see this, suppose the angular speed (the coefficient of $t$ inside the $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions) is $\omega$, so $\vec{Q} = R\cos(\omega t)\hat{i} + R\sin(\omega t)\hat{j}$. Then as $t$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$, the particle $Q$ describes exactly one full circle - so the total distance moved is the circumference $2\pi R$. Then the (constant) speed is $\text{speed} = \dfrac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}} \Rightarrow v =  \dfrac{2\pi R}{2\pi/\omega} = R\omega \Rightarrow \omega = \dfrac{v}{R}$. A shorter way is to differentiate $\vec{Q}$ and equate the magnitude to $v$.

Comment: Oh yeah what was I thinking. Thanks.

Comment: @S.Dan I'll work in that $\theta$ and update the answer when I'm done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15100/discussion-between-s-dan-and-m-vinay).

Answer (score 3):

Use the cosine theorem on triangle POQ:

$x^2=r^{2}+R^{2}-2Rr\cos\left(\frac{v}{R}t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Comment: $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} + \theta) = -\sin(\theta)$

Comment: I forgot to tell about $\theta$ as in the editted question, so $vt$ can be replaced with $\theta$ right?

Comment: $\theta=\omega t$ where $\omega$ is the angular velocity. $v=\omega R$.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but if you need x as a distance , can't we use Pythagore theorem .
In that case the equation would be 
$$
x=\sqrt(PQ^2)=
\sqrt(R^2+r^2)
$$

But that equation does not involve the speed constant.

Comment: This is true only when the particle is exactly to the right or left of $O$ (at the distance $R$). At all other points on the circle, it's wrong.